What is $\int (y'(x))^2 dx$?
By rearranging $(y'(x))^2)$ to $((\frac{dy}{dx})^2)$ I think I can simplify it to $\frac{(dy)^2}{dx}$. Is that valid? I know that treating derivatives as fractions is not always mathematically valid.How else would I do this integral?

I'm pretty sure you can't do this integral without knowledge of what $y$ is.

Indeed, there are elementary functions $y(x)$ for which $\int y'(x)^2 , \mathrm{d}x$ cannot be written as an elementary function. This means that you have no hope of finding one-fits-all formula that expresses this integral as an elementary formula involving $y$ and its derivatives.

"Is that valid?"  No.
